# How add a new fonts on the Webview in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

How can I add new fonts on webview to support others languages.
I use wbeview.loadUrl(string); I wnat tis web view support the new font how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the .ttf of the fonts in the directory assets/, this will give the activity the possibility to use those fonts.